# What is the XML entity number for this character?

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I'm able to encode the 'masculine ordinal operator' like this for my XML file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="AL32UTF8"?> 
 <Calle>       
   <Linea>
       <Lugar>Lugar n&#186;3</Lugar>    
 </Linea> 
 </Calle>
```

However the glyph I'd like to encode is the multibyte character as described in

`select chr(49850) as multibyte_char from dual`

The character look like this, and I call it an `underlined masculine ordinal operator`

[image: chr49850]

**Questions**

What is the Entity Number for this Oracle chr(49850) or how encode this in XML?
Better yet, where are some reference for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they are not different. It just depends on the font whether it appears underlined or not.

How it looks in StackOverflow: º

How it looks in Word for different fonts:

[image: masculine ordinal operator]

There are similar characters, though (from [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinalzeichen)):

```
ᵃ (U+1D43 modifier letter small a)
ᵒ (U+1D52 modifier letter small o)
ᴼ (U+1D3C modifier letter capital o)
° (U+00B0 degree sign)
˚ (U+02DA ring above)
```